# jqGrid how to sort on TimeSpan?

Tags: jqgrid

Want to sort columns (named activitytime) in the grid on a TimeSpan ("hh:mm:ss"), so added the definition:

```
colModel: [
                { name: 'index', index: 'index', width: 42, align: "right", sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 350, sortable: true, sorttype: "text", },
                { name: 'activitytime', index: 'activitytime', width: 110, align: "right", datefmt: "hh:mm:ss", sorttype: "date" },
                ...
            ],
```

That does not work. Is there a way to sort on a TimeSpan (data formatted as "hh:mm:ss")? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is the default `sorttype: "text"` not what you need? Have the data always 8 characters (like `00:00:00` or `23:59:59`)? Do you have empty data in the column? Do you have some spacial cases when sorting of strings do not the same results which you need?

Comment: Right, the sorttype was historically added, however only time of date needed to be displayed. Text type will do. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I'll add short answer so that you cold close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display the data in the form with 8 characters (like `00:00:00` or `23:59:59`) then usage of default `sorttype: "text"` could solve your problem. So you need just remove `sorttype: "date"` which you currently use.